# Norm of matrix and vertex inequality

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Why is it true $||Aj|| \le ||j||$? 
Where $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix and $j$ is a vector.

Matrix $A$ is called the degree adjacency matrix of graph $G$ and is given by formula $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d(i)\cdot d(j)}}$ if $ij \in E(G)$ and $0$ otherwise.

And $d(i)$ is degree of vertex $i$.

Comment: Please provide some context. For instance, how did you come across this question? what are your thoughts on it? What have you tried?

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the "degree adjacency matrix" as you've described it can be written in the form
$$
A = D^{-1/2}MD^{-1/2}
$$ 
where $M$ is the usual adjacency matrix and $D$ is the degree matrix.

Comment: thank you but what next? I really cant figure it out :(

Comment: The next step is to please provide some context. For instance, how did you come across this question? what are your thoughts on it? What have you tried?

Comment: It all came across form $\langle Aj, j \rangle \le ||Aj|| ||j|| \le ||j||^2$ and i didn't know the last inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $v = (\sqrt{d(1)},\dots,\sqrt{d(n)})$ is a vector with positive entries satisfying $Av = v$. It follows by the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) that $1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.  Because $A$ is a symmetric matrix, it follows that the spectral norm of $A$ is $1$, which is to say that $\|Aj\| \leq \|j\|$ for all vectors $j$.